# Can an array of a superclass `EKCalendarItem` store elements that are subclassed, like `EKEvent` and `EKReminder`

Tags: swift, eventkit

I have a calendar viewer in which I would like to use a combination of calendar-events and reminder-events.

Just as Apple provides two different first-party apps, internally, the two are different classes.

But they both sub-class `EKCalendarItem`

I was hoping I could do something like:

`listForCalendarTable:[EKCalendarItem] = []`

And then latter add various `EKEvent` and `EKReminder`, because they are both subclasses `EKCalendarItem`.

When I try this, it seems to silently discard

(Here's code I put into a Swift Playground)

```
        var superClassArray:[EKCalendarItem] = []

        let reminder = EKReminder()
        print (reminder)
        let calEvent = EKEvent()
        print (calEvent)

        superClassArray.append(reminder)
        superClassArray.append(calEvent)
        print (superClassArray)
```

Comment: What do you mean "silently discard"? The code you posted is perfectly fine.

Comment: When I run it, the `superClassArray` prints as "[]" (empty)...

Comment: How does your code get that far? When I copy and paste the code from your question into a Playground, it crashes on the `let reminder = EKReminder()` line. Did you post your real code?

Comment: Yes, no crash, but that's why I suspect my playground is misbehaving some how... I will try to cleanup code inside Xcode project, and update the code. (In the past, my recollection that the appends did not error, but the array remained "[]"... and no crashing in Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of an array of a superclass with multiple subclass types is fine, the problem with your code is the initialization of your `EKReminder` and `EKEvent` objects, both of which need to be passed an `EKEventStore` to be created:

```
    var superClassArray:[EKCalendarItem] = []

    var eventStore = EKEventStore()
    
    var reminder = EKReminder.init(eventStore: eventStore)
    print (reminder)
    let calEvent = EKEvent.init(eventStore: eventStore)
    print (calEvent)
    
    superClassArray.append(reminder)
    superClassArray.append(calEvent)
    print (superClassArray)
```